# Regex for ip validation

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

Hi my regex pattern is

```
^((?:(?:^|\.)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[-4]\d|25[0-5])){4})$
```

this allow `0.0.0.0` but i do not want to allow `0.0.0.0` please someone help me

Comment: Do you need to allow: `1.0.0.0`, `0.1.0.0`, `0.0.1.0`, `0.0.0.1`? (in other words, if there is only one number not equal to zero, can it be at any position?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[1-9])((?:(?:^|\.)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[-4]\d|25[0-5])){4})$
```

You can do this through `positive lookahead.`See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/8

Comment: I know it might not be the case, but this regex is prone to catastrophic backtracking in some very [weird scenarios like this](https://regex101.com/r/yE3oO3/1). Perhaps, the string is not a user's input and will never occur. However, my suggestion works ok even in such cases. Avinash's is also performing great. In general, I'd avoid `.*` if it is not necessary.

Comment: @stribizhev hehehe.........i suspect, that ip address would be possible in year 3050 when population is billions :P

Answer (score 2):

Just add a negative lookahead assertion at the start.

```
^(?!0+\.0+\.0+\.0+$)((?:(?:^|\.)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[-4]\d|25[0-5])){4})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hF0yA0/2)

Answer (score 0):

A look-ahead can be used to set a length limit. In this case, it can be quite concise, since the string should only contain digits and `.` symbol.

Thus, I suggest using `(?![0.]+$)` as we only need to check if we have no `0`s and periods up to the end:

```
^(
 (?![0.]+$)                  # Here is the look-ahead.
 (?:
   (?:^|\.)
   (?:
      \d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[-4]\d|25[0-5]
   )
 ){4}
)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF0eE3/1)

A [one-line JS version](https://regex101.com/r/rF0eE3/2):

```
^((?![0.]+$)(?:(?:^|\.)(?:\d|[1-9][0-9]|1\d{2}|2[-4]\d|25[0-5])){4})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this part of an assignment?

If not, I would use no regex and prefer String#scan :

```
ip_subnets = ip.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) # you can use split('.') instead of scan
ip_subnets.all? { |i| (0..255).include?(i) } && 
  ip_subnets.any? { |i| i != 0 } && 
  ip_subnets.size == 4
```